# Числа 01, 02 ... внутри цикла for

Tags: php, циклы

Пишу такой код

```
<select class="form-control select">
<?php   for ($i = 1; $i < 32; $i++) { ?> 
<option><?php echo $i ; ?></option>
<?php } ;?>
</select>
```

Наверняка уже понятно что внутри селекта идут календарные дни . Всё бы ничего, но вот числа идут без нуля а хотелось бы как ни будь написать числа с нулями. Например 01, 02, 03 и т д.
Если делаю так

```
<?php   for ($i = 01; $i < 32; $i++) { ?>
```

то всё равно числа отображаются по прежнему без нулей , но уже до 25 числа. Как быть чтоб первые числа с 1 до 9 отображались с нулями. )

Comment: Добавьте проверку echo (($i < 10) ? '0' . $i : $i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$leading_zero = sprintf("%02d", $i);
echo $leading_zero;
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Всё работает отлично !

Answer (score 1):

```
<select class="form-control select">
<?php   for ($i = 1; $i < 32; $i++) { ?>
    <option><?php echo str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?></option>
<?php } ;?>
</select>
```

Comment: и Это работает !